# New Gtk.Video() class can't seek()

Tags: python, video, gtk, gstreamer, gtk4

According to [the documentation](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/method.MediaStream.seek.html), this should be enough to seek from the current timestamp to five seconds forwards:

```
def seek_ahead(self, widget, _):
    timestamp = self.stream.get_timestamp()
    self.stream.seek(timestamp + 5000)
```

But it does not seek, only pauses for half a second and then resumes from the current timestamp. And if I try to seek to a precise timestamp, say `stream.seek(5000)` the stream resets to timestamp 0 / start.

All this without *any* error or warning.

What I also tried

- Pausing the stream first
- Using [`seek_success()`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/method.MediaStream.seek_success.html)
- Using [`is_seeking()`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/method.MediaStream.is_seeking.html) (and removing all other inputs) to make sure that no race condition is going on

Of course I tried a lot of video files to make sure the video stream itself was not causing this, in fact all the streams I create are `stream.is_seekable() => True` but no matter what I do I can get the stream to play, to pause, but not to seek.

Comment: According to the docs, `get_timestamp()` returns the time on microseconds, and not on miliseconds as I would expect https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/method.MediaStream.get_timestamp.html . Could you try `self.stream.seek(timestamp + 5000000)` ?